# Why are strings getting cut short after appearing correctly in a drop-down menu?

Tags: php, html, sql, database, web

I'm trying to build a simple web interface that connects to a small database. I've themed the interface to be a roster of the Sochi Olympics. I'm having trouble inserting a new Athlete. New athletes can only be added to an existing team in the database due to a foreign key dependency. To remedy this, I created an array of a column of the table by calling pg_fetch_all_columns. Then I iterate through the array and create a new option tag for each one. The names correctly appear as options on the drop down, but when I try to add it into the database it only includes the first word of the team. For example, "US Men's Curling team" becomes "US". I found this out by calling echo $variable.

PHP Portion that correctly makes the array and formats the drop down:

```
<?php
                $db_handle = pg_connect("host='postgres.cs.wisc.edu' port='5432' dbname='cs564_s14' sslmode='require'") 
                        or die ("Connection failed".pg_last_error()); 
                $queryTeam = "SELECT name from sochi14_schema.team"; 
                $result = pg_exec($db_handle, $queryTeam);
                if (!$result) {
                echo "An error occurred.\n";
                exit();
                }
                $array =pg_fetch_all_columns($result, 0); 
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); ++$i) {
                    echo "<option value=".$array[$i]."> ".$array[$i]." </option>";
                }

                ?>
```

Action that gets called:

```
                if (!isset($_POST['name']) || !isset($_POST['age'])){
                        echo "Name and age of the athlete must be specified";
                        exit();
                    }
                     if (isset($_POST['medals'])){
                        $medals = $_POST['medals'];
                     }else{
                        $medals = "''";
                     }
                    $name = $_POST['name'];
                    $age = $_POST['age'];
                    $team = $_POST['team'];
                    $country = $_POST['country'];

                    echo $name;
                    echo $medals;
                    echo $country;
                    echo $team;



                    if($age < 12){
                    echo "Age must be larger than 12";
                    exit();
                    }

                    if($age > 120){
                    echo "Age must be less than 120";
                    exit();
                    }

                        $db_handle = pg_connect(DATABASE INFO CORRECTLY HANDLED) 
                            or die ("Connection failed".pg_last_error()); 

                        $query = "INSERT into sochi14_schema.athlete values ( '".$name."',
                            ".$age.", '".$medals."', ".$team.", ".$country.")"; 
                        $result = pg_exec($db_handle, $query);

                        if($result){
                            echo "Success: ".$name." has been inserted<br>";
                        }
                        pg_close();
                        ?>
```

Comment: Is it just the first word or does it cut off after each quotes for  example `US Men'`. because if you don't escape that quote it would break your string.

Comment: If you `var_dump($_POST)` they are shown normally?

Comment: It's just the first word. Only the first word ever shows up.

Comment: How do I escape that quote? I tried to add single quotes in the query for team : '".$team."', but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I var_dump($_POST) they still aren't shown normally. ["team"]=> string(6) "Norway"

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...There has to be quotes if the option is more than one word in HTML..Example:

```
'<option value="'.$row['car'].'">' . $row['car'] . '</option>';
```